# Why my jekyll blog on github not work?

Tags: jekyll

http://chenge.github.io, I can see the index page, show 'Hi'. But after I modified the page with 'Hi 3', it did not updated.

repo at: https://github.com/chenge/chenge.github.io

Thanks for help

Comment: Everything seems correct, I would contact support

Answer (score 3):

Your Jekyll blog must be at the root of your repository, not in a `blog` folder.

**Edit** :
If you want to store Jekyll files in `blog`, your have to move your `_config.yml` at the root of your repository and change it like this :

```
source: "blog/"
baseurl: ""
```

**Edit 2** :
I just saw that [you cannot configure the `source` folder on github pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#configuration-overrides).

Comment: But, index.html is at root.